# How do I solve these Nonlinear equations in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I'm new to stackoverflow so hopefully this post follows all the rules and is in the correct place. If there's any problems let me know so I don't do it again! Also I hope a little LaTeX notation is ok for the greek letters and maths operators.

Here goes...

I'm attempting to reproduce a graph from a maths paper as part of my PhD project. This involves solving a set of 4 nonlinear equations in 4 unknowns (a, w, \alpha, \beta), corresponding to in the code. These equations feature a 5th variable, \sigma' (dsigma in the code), however we prescribe a value to this before solving the equations. I also need to define the power

P = 2 * a^2 * w.

I would like to plot a graph of P versus \log(\sigma') for \sigma' in the range \exp(-4) to \exp(-0.5). This therefore requires that I loop through values of \sigma' in that range and solve the nonlinear equations to ultimately determine P for each value of \sigma'. The difficulty of this problem is that the equations contain some integral terms as well as derivatives of these integrals. [The Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuPFr.png), [Integral Terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktkRw.png)

Now I'll explain my implementation. I'll include the code in it's entirety and in order, breaking it up to explain a few bits. The first bit of code is the preamble where I define a few constants that will be used. There is also a comment on how the elements of x represent the unknowns that I mentioned.

```
import scipy.integrate as int
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eta_0 = pow(10, -3)  # background packing fraction
g = (3 - eta_0) / pow(1 - eta_0, 3) + np.log(eta_0) # constant appears in equations
d = 0.001  # finite difference

# x = [ a , w , alpha , beta ]
```

The next few lines of code define functions that I'll call to compute the integral terms in the equations

```
# fns to define the integral terms
# uses 200 to approximate infinity in the integrals

def Omega(x):  
   return int.quad(lambda y: pow(1 / np.cosh(y / x[3]), 2) * pow(1 / np.cosh(y / x[1]), 2), 0, 200)[0]  

def Xi(x):
   return int.quad(lambda y: 2 * ((4 - 2 * eta_0 - 2 * x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2))/pow(1 - eta_0 - (x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)), 2) - (4 - 2 * eta_0) / pow(1 - eta_0, 2)), 0, 200)[0]

def Theta(x):
   return int.quad(lambda y: (eta_0 * np.log(1 + x[2] / eta_0 * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)) + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2) * np.log(eta_0 + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2))), 0, 200)[0]
```

Now I define functions to compute the derivatives of the integral terms. I use a finite difference approximation.

```
# Functions computing the finite difference derivatives of Omega, Xi and Theta

def dOmega_dw(x):  # finite difference
   x2 = np.zeros(4)  # initialise x2
   for j in range(len(x)):
       x2[j] = x[j]
   x2[1] = x[1] + d  # x2 is x perturbed in the direction of derivative
   return (Omega(x2) - Omega(x)) / d

def dOmega_dbeta(x):
   x2 = np.zeros(4)  # initialise x2
   for j in range(len(x)):
      x2[j] = x[j]
   x2[3] = x[3] + d  # x2 is x perturbed in the direction of derivative
   return (Omega(x2) - Omega(x)) / d

def dXi_dalpha(x):
   x2 = np.zeros(4)  # initialise x2
   for j in range(len(x)):
      x2[j] = x[j]
   x2[2] = x[2] + d  # x2 is x perturbed in the direction of derivative
   return (Xi(x2) - Xi(x)) / d

def dTheta_dalpha(x):
   x2 = np.zeros(4)  # initialise x2
   for j in range(len(x)):
      x2[j] = x[j]
   x2[2] = x[2] + d  # x2 is x perturbed in the direction of derivative
   return (Theta(x2) - Theta(x)) / d
```

The system of equations I would like to solve for each \sigma' is then given by:

```
# fn to compute system functions evaluated at x

def fn_vals(x, dsigma):
   f = np.zeros(4)
   f[0] = 1 - 3 * x[2] * x[1] * (Omega(x) - x[1] * dOmega_dw(x))
   f[1] = dsigma + 1 / (2 * pow(x[1], 2)) - (x[2] / x[1]) * (2 * Omega(x) - x[1] * dOmega_dw(x))
   f[2] = 4 * pow(x[0], 2) * x[2] * (Omega(x) - x[3] * dOmega_dbeta(x)) - x[3] * (x[2] * dXi_dalpha(x) - Xi(x)) - 4 * x[3] * (x[2] * dTheta_dalpha(x) - Theta(x))
   f[3] = 4 * x[2] * pow(x[0], 2) * dOmega_dbeta(x) - Xi(x) - 4 * Theta(x) + 4 * x[2] * (1 + g)
   return f
```

Finally, this is my method to solve the equations for values of \sigma' in the range I previously specified and then determine P. It also prints solutions, x, along with those solutions evaluated on system of equations fn_vals(x). Then the plot is drawn up.

```
# Main Method

plot_points = 50  # number of sigma' used from linspace
dsigma = np.linspace(np.exp(-4), np.exp(-0.5), plot_points)  # linear space of sigma'

x0 = np.array([5, 2, .5, 2])  # Initial Guess
P = np.zeros(len(dsigma))  # Initialise Power array

for i in range(len(dsigma)):
   x = scipy.optimize.fsolve(fn_vals, x0, args=(dsigma[i]))
   #x = scipy.optimize.newton_krylov(lambda y: fn_vals(y, dsigma[i]),x0)
   print(str(i) + ' x: ' + str(x))
   print(str(i) + ' f(x): ' + str(fn_vals(x, dsigma[i])))
   P[i] = 2 * x[0] ** 2 * x[1]

plt.plot(np.log(dsigma), P, color='red')
plt.xlabel('logσ\'')
plt.ylabel('P')
plt.ylim((0, 100))
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the code produces warning messages and the graph it produces is nothing like the one that I expect to see i.e. the one from the paper. [Graph my code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VrZB.png). [Graph I am aiming for (red curve)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyMkp.png). The x-axis of the curve i'm trying to achieve is actually mislabelled with \log(\sigma) rather than \log(\sigma'), but that's of no consequence.

My questions is therefore how do I fix these error messages and more generally, is there an issue with my overall implementation? Something worth mentioning is that the code slows down considerably as the for loop gets to larger \sigma' values. I see no good reason for this since changing the \sigma' simply changes a single term in one of the equations slightly, and so does not introduce additional complexity as it increases (as far as I can tell, that is!!)

Console output:

```
C:\Users\jr00427\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py
0 x: [2.17223218 3.99095975 0.06229124 2.20338412]
0 f(x): [ 8.58901839e-12 -1.41724826e-12  5.19292387e-11  7.05557834e-12]
1 x: [2.37561955 3.08515307 0.1046654  1.67791836]
1 f(x): [ 1.33013378e-10  7.77328202e-12 -5.00405273e-11  2.37623254e-10]
2 x: [2.53243759 2.62483192 0.14401699 1.44845902]
2 f(x): [ 6.08402217e-14  4.68194927e-13 -6.63180622e-12  3.13977733e-11]
3 x: [2.66874353 2.33907902 0.18012946 1.32517916]
3 f(x): [-5.18762810e-12 -3.58851837e-13 -2.00288675e-11 -8.10018719e-13]
C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
return int.quad(lambda y: (eta_0 * np.log(1 + x[2] / eta_0 * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)) + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2) * np.log(eta_0 + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)))
C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py:29: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
   If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
   the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
   local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
   probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
   on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
return int.quad(lambda y: (eta_0 * np.log(1 + x[2] / eta_0 * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)) + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2) * np.log(eta_0 + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)))
C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py:19: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated.
return int.quad(lambda y: pow(1 / np.cosh(y / x[3]), 2) * pow(1 / np.cosh(y / x[1]), 2)
C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py:24: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
underestimated.
return int.quad(lambda y: 2 * ((4 - 2 * eta_0 - 2 * x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2))/pow(1 - eta_0 - (x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)), 2) - (4 - 2 * eta_0) / pow(1 - eta_0, 2))
C:/Users/jr00427/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/fig1.py:29: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated.
return int.quad(lambda y: (eta_0 * np.log(1 + x[2] / eta_0 * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)) + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2) * np.log(eta_0 + x[2] * pow(1 / np.cosh(y), 2)))
4 x: [2.79424801 2.14206677 0.21321325 1.25261518]
4 f(x): [ 1.79067872e-12  5.53390667e-13 -1.31199496e-11  8.22670820e-11]
5 x: [2.91363137 1.99713794 0.24358556 1.20844003]
5 f(x): [-1.94449123e-10 -5.12074549e-11 -5.97554228e-10 -4.86269469e-09]
6 x: [3.02952519 1.88573693 0.27156854 1.18189116]
6 f(x): [ 2.65837463e-10 -9.57736668e-12  5.44213119e-10 -1.18931176e-09]
7 x: [3.14357663 1.79736488 0.29745628 1.16713633]
7 f(x): [ 3.66652264e-11 -8.64475158e-13  3.57718299e-10 -2.08828954e-10]
8 x: [3.25690492 1.72559242 0.32150642 1.16074372]
8 f(x): [ 2.51010324e-12  3.94073663e-13 -5.16942045e-12  1.63424829e-12]
9 x: [3.37032322 1.66624182 0.34394086 1.16056739]
9 f(x): [ 8.99047503e-12  1.85185201e-12 -1.26084920e-10 -1.56481939e-10]
10 x: [3.48445711 1.61647025 0.36494952 1.16520186]
10 f(x): [ 1.51456181e-10  1.84359750e-11 -1.86038251e-09 -3.35343220e-09]
11 x: [3.59981239 1.57427044 0.38469474 1.17369322]
11 f(x): [ 2.68745026e-11  5.78193049e-12 -8.87578899e-10 -8.24673663e-11]
12 x: [3.71681645 1.5381816  0.40331557 1.18537603]
12 f(x): [-2.52327048e-11 -7.29138971e-12  1.18753518e-09 -2.03906225e-10]
13 x: [3.83584463 1.50711355 0.42093148 1.19977648]
13 f(x): [-2.59998689e-11 -1.58172364e-11  2.84988366e-09 -1.40117162e-09]
14 x: [3.95723796 1.48023525 0.43764556 1.21655242]
14 f(x): [ 4.40729675e-11 -1.04632414e-11  8.94391228e-11 -1.26940236e-10]
15 x: [4.08131539 1.45690165 0.45354711 1.2354549 ]
15 f(x): [ 2.13939977e-12 -2.95874436e-13  4.08411083e-11  3.81827903e-12]
16 x: [4.20838276 1.43660421 0.4687139  1.25630271]
16 f(x): [-1.07911458e-11  1.32516220e-12 -3.45652973e-09  1.35364253e-09]
17 x: [4.33873954 1.41893662 0.48321392 1.27896513]
17 f(x): [-1.60516045e-12  2.15716334e-13  8.93907171e-12 -1.02069464e-11]
18 x: [4.47268409 1.4035705  0.49710688 1.30335004]
18 f(x): [ 4.24849045e-12 -1.23717703e-12  1.20773169e-10 -1.39364076e-11]
19 x: [4.61051803 1.39023772 0.51044549 1.32939549]
19 f(x): [ 5.78759263e-13  6.64357458e-13 -1.60298441e-11  3.89155375e-11]
20 x: [4.75254994 1.37871755 0.52327641 1.35706372]
20 f(x): [-9.43467526e-13 -2.15827356e-12 -7.86481991e-13 -2.03732142e-10]
21 x: [4.89909869 1.36882688 0.53564116 1.3863368 ]
21 f(x): [-2.78221890e-13  3.82582854e-13  3.28626015e-11  1.19682042e-10]
22 x: [5.05049648 1.36041294 0.54757682 1.41721355]
22 f(x): [ 9.33837452e-11  1.42422740e-11 -8.25012636e-09 -6.23565910e-09]
23 x: [5.20709183 1.35334762 0.55911661 1.44970722]
23 f(x): [ 7.51620988e-13  3.42614825e-13  2.43605136e-11 -6.86162238e-11]
24 x: [5.36925249 1.34752316 0.5702904  1.48384394]
24 f(x): [ 7.73503483e-12  3.11162207e-12  1.21335253e-09 -6.22270235e-10]
25 x: [5.53736851 1.34284865 0.58112515 1.51966152]
25 f(x): [-2.74983147e-10  4.06052969e-12  2.11696025e-08  1.47733950e-08]
26 x: [5.71185528 1.33924738 0.59164527 1.55720875]
26 f(x): [ 2.51110244e-12  1.37390099e-12  5.69415626e-10 -2.89000823e-10]
27 x: [5.89315698 1.33665465 0.60187293 1.59654494]
27 f(x): [ 3.32889272e-12  5.01754194e-12  9.32416633e-09 -9.03774833e-10]
28 x: [6.08175009 1.33501608 0.61182831 1.63773973]
28 f(x): [ 3.05033776e-12  3.52717855e-12  5.88860027e-09 -4.02114786e-10]
29 x: [6.27814738 1.33428619 0.62152985 1.68087312]
29 f(x): [ 6.07291994e-13  1.09035003e-12  2.63212208e-09 -7.91580135e-11]
30 x: [6.48290222 1.33442729 0.63099445 1.72603569]
30 f(x): [ 1.54798396e-12  3.75588449e-12  5.64094460e-09 -3.88435950e-10]
31 x: [6.6966134  1.33540861 0.64023763 1.77332899]
31 f(x): [ 1.82942550e-12  5.65669733e-12  9.27171229e-09 -2.74568812e-10]
32 x: [6.91993047 1.33720551 0.64927366 1.8228661 ]
32 f(x): [-4.96491737e-13  1.39122047e-12  2.48073828e-09 -2.24294361e-10]
33 x: [7.15355982 1.33979896 0.65811575 1.8747724 ]
33 f(x): [-9.73665593e-13  5.70654635e-14  1.58705671e-09  6.05054673e-10]
34 x: [7.39827148 1.34317504 0.6667761  1.92918642]
34 f(x): [-2.40674147e-12 -2.71782596e-13  3.28928618e-09  4.33761471e-10]
35 x: [7.65490678 1.34732459 0.67526603 1.98626102]
35 f(x): [ 3.39795969e-11  5.65969493e-12 -5.47825794e-08 -3.73836073e-09]
36 x: [7.92438721 1.35224294 0.68359609 2.04616461]
36 f(x): [-3.82072152e-12 -1.14885879e-12  3.55177843e-09 -8.76771544e-10]
37 x: [8.20772441 1.35792973 0.69177608 2.10908273]
37 f(x): [-3.35331762e-12 -4.57078819e-13  6.45956888e-09 -3.00442338e-10]
38 x: [8.50603162 1.36438876 0.69981519 2.17521979]
38 f(x): [ 4.41535697e-12  4.16777723e-13 -3.25887761e-09  8.72297790e-10]
39 x: [8.82053697 1.37162796 0.70772201 2.24480114]
39 f(x): [ 1.52505786e-11 -5.03452835e-12 -1.05404521e-08  1.63349156e-09]
40 x: [9.15259869 1.37965939 0.71550461 2.31807548]
40 f(x): [-1.54432023e-12  4.28101998e-12 -2.21988481e-08 -9.88716664e-10]
41 x: [9.50372283 1.38849928 0.72317057 2.39531758]
41 f(x): [-3.16764392e-11  8.52407034e-12 -8.59034888e-09 -3.73157683e-09]
42 x: [9.87558377 1.3981682  0.73072706 2.47683154]
42 f(x): [ 5.08562081e-11 -2.41295872e-12 -1.26152932e-07  6.87874646e-10]
43 x: [10.27004828  1.40869121  0.73818084  2.56295449]
43 f(x): [-8.52651283e-13 -3.46722651e-13  6.32552410e-09  3.05883319e-10]
44 x: [10.68920363  1.42009813  0.74553833  2.65406095]
44 f(x): [-5.94775340e-11 -3.21842553e-12  3.37865455e-07  5.49956347e-09]
45 x: [11.13539076  1.43242391  0.75280561  2.75056791]
45 f(x): [ 6.83897383e-14  6.65023592e-13 -1.48019073e-08 -3.61112029e-10]
46 x: [11.61124336  1.44570895  0.75998848  2.85294078]
46 f(x): [-4.19131396e-12 -6.77458090e-13 -8.53521698e-11 -3.44803297e-10]
47 x: [12.11973447  1.45999971  0.76709249  2.96170039]
47 f(x): [-9.09827769e-12  4.06008560e-13  3.41526398e-08 -1.99264605e-10]
48 x: [12.6642319   1.47534924  0.77412292  3.07743127]
48 f(x): [ 3.03934655e-12 -6.43929354e-14 -8.62290594e-08 -1.41965728e-09]
C:\Users\jr00427\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:175: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
   improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.
   warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
49 x: [8.96606493 1.47419045 0.71120114 2.44107678]
49 f(x): [-0.14923     0.08035658 -0.00437131 -0.00085175]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Probably a better question for someone in your lab or your advisor since this is a more implementation and not programming question. I'd be willing to bet it's your equations that are wrong (or this function is unstable and not easily convergent). I'm partial to using sympy: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

You'll be able to check your equations symbolically before substituting values in

Comment: Looks like you've done a lot of great work, I have only a few generalized comments. (1) Call a quadrature function specially designed for infinite intervals instead of a general-purpose one with a large upper bound. In the original QUADPACK, that's named QAGI, dunno what it might be in Scipy. (2) Verify your integrals are getting computed OK. In particular it seems at first glance that the second one (Xi[1] I guess) might blow up somewhere in the middle of the range. You would want to verify it doesn't, or work around the pole if it does.

Comment: (3) Is your numerical solution valid? Try substituting the solution you find back into the equations. (4) Computing derivatives via finite differences is problematic. Try computing them symbolically. Sympy could help with that. If that doesn't work out, try an algorithm which doesn't require derivatives. Good luck and have fun, looks like a good problem.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions.  @DylanMadisetti, my advisors happen to be the guys who wrote the paper and they can't figure out why my code doesn't work. Frustrating positition to be in! We're confident in the equations as I've derived them independently and they match the paper.

Comment: @RobertDodier The console output I posted in my question shows a list of solutions and the corresponding equation values when substituted ( x and f(x) ). But these, of course, are evaluated using the same code I'm not confident in!
I'll check out the specialised integrators you mentioned, although I'm pretty confident with the one I'm using. For the paramter values I've tried they seem to match up with mathematica.
You both mentioned SymPy so I'll look into that. Not familiar with python packages yet... this is my second script, the first being a hello world haha

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the implementation of your equations, not the equations themselves :^) We all know there's a big gap between things working in theory and thing actually working, that's where a symbolic solver can come in handy. I would start by testing a fixed point. Both of your charts _start_ at different values

Comment: @JamesRowe You could ask this same question (actually you can try to transfer it) to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions The people there are experts in computational science and may be able to help you much more.

Comment: One thing that I thought about is to use Cauchy integration in order to calculate the partial derivatives of your three functions. Possibly even the the derivatives of the big equation-functions. Basically, your functions are all real analytic and therefore extend as complex analytic. Then use Cauchy,s integration formula (numerical version of that of course) to calculate various derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function